# Issue understanding modification of variable in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm quite new to jupyter and just can't figure out how this work :

With these 3 blocks of code, a multiple execution of the 3rd one make n incremental, i.e. [1,2], then [1,3], [1,4], etc

```
n = [1,2]
```

--

```
def fonction(x): 
  y=x
  y[1]=x[1]+1
  return y
```

--

```
res = fonction(n)
print(res)
```

This is the minimal example i can provide. I don't understand why the variable n is modified though it's only the argument in the 3rd block (and the 2nd block isn't modifying the argument of the function !)

Thanks a lot for your patience explaining 101 jupyter to this old engineer, sincerely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are writing `y = x` inside of `fonction` that is not giving `y` the value contained in `x`, but rather making y point to the value of `x`. In this case `y` is pointing to `x` and `x` is pointing to `n` (via input of `fonction`) therefore `y[1] =`  will assign a value to the variable which is stored in the location that `y` is pointing to... Since y is pointing to the same location as `n` it changes that list. This means that when you reference `n` again it is still pointing to the same list, but the list has been modified via `y[1] = x[1] + 1`.

You can fix this issue by using `y = x[:]` which will create an entirely new list for `y` so that it does not point to the list stored in `n`.

This can be applied to your code like so:

```
def fonction(x): 
  y=x[:] #notice the change here
  y[1]=x[1]+1
  return y
```

Comment: Ok, this clears up a little. How do I prevent that ? By creating a brand new y at the beginning of the function and adding value one after another ? 
Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Victorien as I stated in the answer, use `y = x[:]` instead of `y=x` this will create a new list and location for `y`. See the code block in my answer with the updated function.